# Understanding die, der and das

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I learn noun genders better?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-learn-noun-genders-better)

A key thing I struggled with in German was the use of **die**, **der** and **das**. I vaguely understand that one means masculine, one means feminine and the other means else(?).

Do I need to learn which of these belongs to each noun individually? Or is there some kind of pattern that can help me use these correctly when saying things like:

the house
the car

Comment: Keep in mind that this is only a *grammatical gender*. They could as well be named *foo*, *bar* and *baz* for all the connection they have with human genders.

Comment: The title is too vague, please edit to be more precise.

Comment: You should learn each Noun with its article and the audio memory is your friend. I am using iPhone application [DieDerDas](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diederdas/id524165230?mt=8&uo=4). Here is the lite [online version](http://diederdas.com)

Comment: For both "house" and "car", "the" is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you do pretty much have to learn them word by word. There are no 100% reliable rules but there are some useful rules of thumb that can help, for instance:

- Some word patterns tend to have a predictable gender. For example, nouns derived from a verb and ending *-ung* tend to be feminine, such as *die Erzählung* or *die Entschuldigung*. But beware other *-ung* words like *der Schwung*.
- Diminutives (ending *-chen* or *-lein*) are almost always neuter (*das Mädchen*, *das Fräulein*, etc.) even when (as in both of those cases) the meaning might lead us to expect a feminine noun.
- Words adopted from other languages tend to adopt the gender of their native German synonym. So you sometimes see *das Girl*, the same neuter gender as *das Mädchen*. One of my favourites is *Single*: *die Single* is a 9" vinyl record (like *die Platte*), *der Single* is an unmarried man, and *das Single* is a singles match (e.g. in tennis, like *das Spiel*).

I'm sure other people can add other helpful guidelines below.

I always compare this to pronunciation in English. In German, pronunciation is phonetic and very preditable (e.g. *-au-* is always preferred the same way) whereas in English it's very unpredictable and has to be learnt word by word (*cough*, *though*, *through*, *bought*, etc.). The flip side is that in English we don't have grammatical gender and our word for 'the' is very simple (it's 'the' :), whereas in German the gender has to be learn by rote. You regularly hear small German children being corrected on their noun genders in just the same way English-speaking kids have their pronunciation corrected.

Answer (score 10):

**Der, die and das** are definite articles. You decide which you have to use depending on the gender of the noun. In the German language there are three genders:

1. masculine -> der
2. feminine -> die
3. neuter -> das

For some nouns it is obvious which gender they are:

- **die** Frau - the woman
- **der** Mann - the man
- **das** Auto, **das** Haus - the car, the house

But other times it is not so obvious:

- **das** Mädchen - the girl
- **der** Tisch - the table
- **die** Tasche - the bag

So you have almost no other choice but to learn the gender of the noun along with the noun.

There is some more discussion about this topic in [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-learn-noun-genders-better).

Comment: Learning each noun along with its gender seems like the only strategy.. That's a shame. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's not completely random, and native German speakers have a quite good sense what the gender of a word is, even if they haven't heard the word before. However this doesn't always work and it seems also not trivial to express this intuition as a set of rules.

Comment: As a native German speaker, I cannot remember that I ever had to learn a set of rules to determine the gender of a noun. I learn more about the German language now, that I observe others that learn it. I did not want to give @Marty a false sense of hope by pretending that there is a concise set of rules ;-). And after all, learning the gender of a noun is not that bad... `der Leiter`, `die Leiter`, `der Rost`, `das Rost`... I have great respect for people who choose to learn German.

Comment: Why is it obious that _Auto_ and _Haus_ are neutral? I think it is not. You just have to learn it.

Comment: I think it's "obvious" because they are *things* and *things* are supposed to be neutral. In any case, because there are so many exceptions you could argue that no gender is obvious.