# Is it "der" or "die" Chicorée? And other multi-gender words?

Tags: noun, gender

From the dictionary:

- Leo.org: [der (auch: die) Chicorée](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=Chicor%C3%A9e)
- Duden: [Chi­co­rée, der oder die](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Chicoree)

Why are there two gender for the word *Chicorée*? Is it because of plural?

If not, what is the reason? Are there other words that are also multi-gendered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the gender of new words established?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/how-is-the-gender-of-new-words-established)

Comment: I don't think Chicoree is a new word though.

Comment: @alvas Crissov means perhaps, "new" in the sense that it's a Gallicism, hence it was "new in German" once.

Comment: Also: der/die/das Joghurt, der/die/das Dschungel, die/das Cola

Comment: Also: der/die/das Band (doch mit jeweils verschiedener Bedeutung).

Comment: @c.p. In writing, it looks good; but not so much if spoken. I only know a question that goes the other way around (Heißt es der Coup, die Kuh oder das Q?). Maybe we can find one that works both in writing and spoken...

Comment: Quite often the meaning changes with the article (der/das Tor, der/die/das Single), but sometimes a word has more than one gender, often but not always depending on the region. That's languages for you, I am afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question: As a native German speaker I only heard "der Chicorée". I've never heard a plural form of Chicorée. Wiktionary also says, there is no plural form.

There are some German words, which have different genders based on the local dialect, like das/die Mofa, der/das Prospekt, die/der Butter, der/das Teller, das/der Gummi etc. (The first of each is the gender, which I use and which I heard most)

And like c.p. mentioned, there are German words that have different meanings based on their gender (der Band (anderes Wort für das Buch), die Band (eine Musikgruppe), das Band (anderes Wort für die Schnur) or das Messer (engl.: the knife, ein Schneidwerkzeug), der Messer (ein Messwerkzeug), die Messer (Pluralform von das oder der Messer)).

Comment: I think a sharper distinction should be made between dialect and regional variants of High German. _Der_ Butter is basically wrong, even though it's sometimes used in Viennese and other dialects. Prospekt, on the other hand, can be well be used with both _der_ or _das_ in written standard German as well.

Comment: That's sometimes hard to differentiate. I moved from northern Germany to southern Germany a few years ago. Here are people who clearly talk with a dialect that's hard to understand and people who talk High German but with a few words mixed up (like `das Teller` instead of `der Teller` or `der Radio` instead of `das Radio` or words like `heben` instead of `halten` or `schaffen` instead of `arbeiten`) is that a regional variant of High German or is it a dialect or maybe a dialect-affected regional variant of High German?

Comment: @Dorian I'm from Swabia and jokingly call myself "bilingual" - if I speak dialect, I say "das Tunnel" (emphasis on last syllable), otherwise "der Tunnel" (emphasis on first). Same with "der/das Salz". And of course there is my pet peeve "das(!) Apfelschorle". In my - admittedly not scientific - opinion it's not mangeled Standard German but simply dialect. Also note there is the so-called [Honoratiorenschwäbisch](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwäbischer_Dialekt#Mischformen).

Comment: @Ingmar I am confused that someone from the South calls the regional variants ‘wrong’. *Der Butter* is about as wrong as *das Cola*.

Comment: That is demonstratively untrue. _Das Cola_ is standard Austrian German (although perhaps, as a brand name, not the best of examples. _Das Keks_ works just as well, if not better), _der Butter_ is, well, dialect. You can (as Austrian: will) use the former in writing, unlike the latter which has no place in written communication.

Comment: @Ingmar: Seit wann ist Cola ein Markenname? Für welche Marke genau? Oder ist "Das Cola" ein Markenname, so wie "Die Partei"?

Comment: No, but it's the same for _das_ Coca Cola and _das_ Coke which are.

Answer (score 0):

Da Chicorée ein französisches Wort ist, kann natürlich  Unsicherheit in Bezug auf das Geschlecht eintreten. Im westlichen Regionen wie dem Saarland, wo man enge Berührung mit Französisch hat , wird man wissen, dass das französische Wort feminin ist und wohl "die" sagen.  Andere Regionen lassen sich wohl von "der Salat, der Lauch etc "  beeinflussen. Im übrigen glaube ich, dass Chicorée im Rückzug ist und dass man heute Endiviensalat sagt. Fügungen, wo man Chicorée mit bestimmten Artikel gebraucht dürften auch selten sein; schon das könnte ein Grund sein warum beim Genus Unsicherheit herrscht, was übrigens bei ausländischen Wörtern häufiger vorkommt.

Comment: Zwei Anmerkungen:

Erstens: Bei Fremdwörtern aus modernen Sprachen
ist die Übernahme des Genus der Ursprungssprache die unwahrscheinlichste
unter allen nur denkbaren Erklärungen für das Genus im Deutschen.
(Bei Übernahmen aus dem Lateinischen und Altgriechischen sieht es
anders aus.)

Zweitens: Chicorée und Endivie gehören beide zur Gattung *Cichorium*,
sind aber unterschiedliche Pflanzen. Die Verwirrung kommt daher,
daß sich Deutsche und Franzosen bei der Namensgebung nicht einig
sind: dt. *Chicorée* = frz. *Endive*, dt. *Endivie* = frz. *Chicorée endive*
oder *Chicorée de Belgique*.