# Der oder die HTTP-Request?

Tags: article, gender

Heißt es **der** oder **die** HTTP-Request? Ich denke, es muss **der** Request heißen, kann es aber nicht begründen. Mein Kollege meint, es ist die **Request**, da es ja auch die Anfrage heißt und bei englischen Worten die Artikel von der deutschen Übersetzung übernommen wird.
Was ist richtig und warum?

Comment: One of many similar [questions](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/4714/1696).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fremdworte, die aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche übernommen werden, erhalten ihr Geschlecht per Konvention. Man kann in diesem Prozess der Konventionsfindung ein paar Regularitäten beobachten, aber daraus lassen sich allein schon deskriptiv keine hunderprozentig belastbaren Gesetze ableiten. (Es lässt sich etwa beobachten, dass Fremdworte ihr Geschlecht ändern und für alle einfacheren Regeln lassen sich Ausnahmen finden.) Mehr Details dazu findest du in der allgemeineren Frage [Wonach richtet sich das Geschlecht eines Anglizismus?](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73379/15393) oder auch in wissenschaftlichen Artikeln, etwa [Agnieszka Nyenhuis, Karin Pittner: *Faktoren der Genuszuweisung – ein Vergleich anhand von Anglizismen und Polonismen*, in: Germanica Wratislaviensia Bd. 136 (2012), S. 123-147.](http://staff.germanistik.rub.de/karin-pittner/wp-content/uploads/sites/22/2020/10/2012_GenusAnglizismenPolonismen.pdf)

Schließlich würde, selbst wenn eine stabile deskriptive Regel bekannt wäre, diese die Sprecher:innen des Deutschen nicht binden, wie sie bei einem neuen auftauchenden Fremdwort zu verfahren hätten.

Man kann normativ also nur konstatieren, dass sowohl *die Request* als auch *der Request* korrekt sind.

Comment: Grundsätzlich völlig richtig, aber fachsprachlich ist in der IT praktisch ausschließlich _der [Change-|Pull-|Feature-]Request_ üblich. Das sieht bei _Quest_ (Aufgabe in Abenteuerspielen) schon anders aus, wobei ich auch dort zum Maskulinum tendiere.

Comment: @Crissov Ich arbeite als Programmierer und habe bisher immer nur _die Pull-Request_ (oder auch _die PR_) gehört oder gesagt. Ich kann dir daher bei deinem "praktisch ausschließlich" nicht so richtig zustimmen. Ich spreche allerdings auch nur sehr selten deutsch auf Arbeit.

Comment: Vielleicht gibt es regionale Unterschiede. Bevor ich das gestern so definitiv geäußert habe, bin ich vorsichtshalber die DWDS-Ergebnisse durchgegangen: die waren allesamt maskulin (oder unbestimmt).