# What form of "the" to use for a noun?

Tags: word-choice, article

I am basically struggling to make sense of when to use the *der*, *die*, *das* etc. Even though all the forms are the same word, i.e. *the*. But when to use these forms in what condition?

I even tried the vowel and consonant logic but could not find any?

Comment: No, they are not the same word :) English just happens to have no grammatical gender. And you will just have to learn by heart which gender each noun has - no way around it. There are some crude rules where the article depends on the suffix, but in the long run these will not help you.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-better-learn-noun-genders

Comment: The article depends on case and gender.

Answer (score 2):

English has almost lost it's grammatical genders. They only exists for persons, and here only as pronouns:

> A man has a beard. - The man has a beard. - **He** has a beard.
>   A woman wears a dress. - The woman wears a dress. - **She** wears a dress.
>   A baby sleeps - The baby sleeps - **It** sleeps.

In German:

> **Ein** Mann hat einen Bart. - **Der** Mann hat einen Bart. - **Er** hat einen Bart.
>   **Eine** Frau trägt ein Kleid. - **Die** Frau trägt ein Kleid. - **Sie** trägt ein Kleid.
>   **Ein** Baby schläft. - **Das** Baby schläft. - **Es** schläft.

In English you use for everything else always **it**, and you always use the same article: Either **the** or **a/an**. (Pets, ships, cars and a few other things are sometimes excludes from this rule, they also can be *he* or *she*.)

But German makes much more use of this concept, that exists in english only as *he/she/it*.

In German you also have three kinds of personal pronouns, also depending on the gender, like in english. But there are some facts about grammatical Gender, that you must get into your brain:

1. Grammatical Gender ist not strictly bound to biological gender.
2. Also non-person-words (i.e. every word) can be *he* and *she* in German.
3. Grammatical gender ist not a property of the thing that is named by a word. It is a property of the word itself.

This rules apply to all languages with genders, not just to German.

Here are consequences of this rules for German:

ad 1:
There are German words for people, that have a grammatical gender that does not match with the biological gender. Most famous example: **Das Mädchen** (in english: the girl) this word is not female but neuter.

ad 2:
This is the most important fact. I translate the following examples as if there was genders for things in english too:

> **Der** Mond scheint. Siehst du **ihn**? - The moon is shining. Do you see **him**? (*Der Mond* is male).
>   **Die** Sonne geht auf. Siehst du **sie**? - The sun is rising. Do you see **her**? (*Die Sonne* is female).
>   **Das** Mädchen tanzt. Siehst du **es**? - The girl is dancing. Do you see **it**? (*Das Mädchen* is neuter).

ad 3:
There are many German word for the english word *car* (there are also many english synonyms). Some of them have different genders, but they all name the same physical object. (I again use German grammar in the english translations):

> neuter: **Das** Auto ist gelb. **Es** ist gelb. - The car is yellow. **It** is yellow.
>   male: **Der** Wagen ist gelb. **Er** ist gelb. - The car is yellow. **He** is yellow.
>   female: **Die** Karre ist gelb. **Sie** ist gelb. - The car is yellow. **She** is yellow.

Just to confuse you even more (but it has to be said):
Almost every languages contains homonyms, which are identical words that mean different things. Take the english word »driver« as an example. This can be a person who drives a car, but it can also be a special kind of software of a computer that helps the operating system to communicate with it's hardware devices. You must learn, that homonyms are different words, and so can have different genders.

Famous German example: »Band«. A Band can be a music band, a volume of a book, or a ribbon that you can put in your hair. And all three *Band*s have different genders:

> male: **Der** Band 5 aus der Harry-Potter-Reihe ist ausverkauft. - Volume 5 of Harry Potter is sold out.
>   female: **Die** Band, die gestern gespielt hat, war gut. - The Band who played yesterday was good.
>   neuter: **Das** Band in ihrem Haar ist rot. - The ribbon in her hair is red.

(Those 3 different words also have 2 different pronunciations. The female music-Band is pronounced like the english word ”band“. The ribbon and the volume are pronounced the German way)

---

There are many languages with genders. Italien has two genders, male and female (there is no **it** in Italian). Swedish also has two, but here are male and female the same one gender which is named *utrum* and the other gender is *neutrum* (which is neuter in fact). German and many other european Languages has the three genders described above.

But there are also languages with much more "genders". Suaheli, spoken in parts of Afrika, has 22 "nominal classes" as they are called there. There are classes for male and female people, but also for long and round things, or for invisible things. But also that in Suaheli you have so much more classes, they seem easier to learn than genders of european languages, because european languages like German have almost no systematics in how a word gets its gender.

The best way to lern German genders is to learn the gender of every noun separate. This means: Do not learn non this way:

> <del>milk = Milch</del>
>   <del>bread = Brot</del>
>   <del>tea = Tee</del>

Learn ALL nouns this way:

> the milk = **die** Milch ("*die*" because "Milch" is female)
>   the bread = **das** Brot ("*das*" because "Brot" is neuter)
>   the tea = **der** Tee ("*der*" because "Tee" is male)

And there is some bad news if you learn more languages: Different languages sometimes do not use the same genders for corresponding word. Example: The sun is female in German, but male in Italien. The Moon on the other hand is male in German but female in Italien. What you have to learn from it (again): The gender is a property of the word, not of the thing that is named by the word.

Comment: Actually, English speakers will usually not use “it” to refer to babies.

Comment: @CarstenS: Supposed they don't know the biological gender of the baby: Which pronoun do they use?

Comment: I had to google this before I commented, they would avoid using a pronoun. They treat babies just like other people.

Comment: Or use "he" *and* "she", switching somewhat randomly in a text. There is apparently a *slight* preference for "she", but that might be to counter the long-standing default(-ish) "he".

Comment: @CarstenS No, I can confirm that English people will (sometimes) use *it* to refer to babies. ‘I sat behind a baby in the aeroplane. *It* was crying the entire flight.’

Comment: @Jan, maybe, I still think you should try to avoid referring to someone's baby ad “it” when talking to them, even if you do not know whether it's a boy or girl. (The Wikipedia article on “it” mentions fixed expressions like “s it a boy or a girl”, though.)

Comment: @CarstenS I can totally agree with avoiding *it*, especially if the parents are within hearing range ;)