# German Grammar Regarding Gender

Tags: gender

I am rather new to the German language but I have been following it since I have an interest in it. The first problem I encountered in my studies is that I couldn't help but wonder, how does the German language differentiate the gender of nouns and other words. Is there a pattern or is it just pure classification?

Comment: See http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-better-learn-noun-genders

Comment: Danke schön Herr Takkat!!

Comment: What do you mean with other words? Verbs, for instance? Verbs don't have gender. The (gender of nouns) and (other words)? Hm? What's the question? The language itself does not differentiate, the users of the language do things, and they do it by using the language.

Answer (score 1):

- *Differentiate the gender of nouns:* Here one has to deal with it, you just have to learn the gender of almost every substantive (although there are a bunch of rules [albeit with exceptions], which in very few cases help to you to determine it).
- *"Other words"*: Only nouns have a gender. Some of the "other words" sort of acquire a gender when combined with a noun. At a beginner's level, all words you need are registered in the respective Wiktionary's entry to that word. For instance if you need *rot* (red) you to to:

> https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:rot

<sup>and after opening it by a second time you no longer wonder about the many entries : )</sup>