# Can't make sense of the way dict.cc data is compiled

Tags: word-usage, dictionary

I looked up the word "Alt" in dict.cc and this is what i see under ADJ:

alt | älter | am ältesten
alter | alte | altes
ältester | älteste | ältestes

What are these? Are they all superlative adjectives of alt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your mouse cursor over these words and you'll get an explanation. Did try that on a desktop PC with chrome browser.

dict.cc is the frontend of a database, so any input gives more then one result.

You put "alt" in the input field and dict.cc gives you:

**ADJ   alt | älter | am ältesten
alter | alte | altes 
ältester | älteste | ältestes

NOUN    der Alt | die Alte [Chorstimme] 
NOUN    der Alt [Fluss] | - 
NOUN    das Alt [Altbier] | die Alt 
SYNO    alt | antiquarisch | Alt | Altbier ...**

Which means:

There is an adjective "alt" with the comparisons: "älter" and "am ältesten".

The masculine form is "alter" as in "alter Baum" (old tree), the female form is "alte" as in "alte Frau" (old woman) and the neuter form is "altes" as in "altes Haus" (old house).

Superlative forms: "ältester, älteste, ältester" (m,f,n)

There is a masculine noun "Alt", wich is the German word for the Alto in a (classical) choir. "Die Alte" is the (rarely used but correct) plural form of it.

dict.cc also found a name of a river "der Alt". This is actually the German name of the Romanian river "Olt".

Another noun dict.cc found is "das Alt" a type of beer (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altbier). The plural is "die Alt".

The last line (can be extended via mouse) gives synonyms.

Comment: Yeah but the tool-tip is the same for all of them. Can you elaborate more on how these relate to alt. Why there is **9** instead of **3**?

Answer (score 6):

The dict.cc entries for adjectives are set up as follows (explained in the tooltip):

First line: positive, comparative, superlative

Second line: strong declension, for male, female and neuter

Third line (not always present): Superlatives for male, female and neuter

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are superlative adjecties to alt (old, older, oldest) for male/female/objects.

Maybe it would help if you can post the sentence? Or at least a part of it?

Comment: How did you find out their gender?

Comment: @pouya [This post about learning gender](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-better-learn-noun-genders) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @pouya I edited my answer. Hopefully you may now understand the output of dict.cc.